# What is the effect of assigning a sign to $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

What is the effect of assigning a sign to $0$?  In Calculus, $0^+$ means the right side of $0$ whereas $0^-$ means the left side of $0$ in a limit.

But other than that, what are the effects when we try to give $0$ a sign?

What are the consequences?

Comment: I don't really understand your question - can you give an example of "trying to give $0$ a sign?" To me it seems that $0^+, 0^-$ *aren't* examples of this; we also take limits to $2^-$, or $2^+$, etc.

Comment: @goblin What tag should I use?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I don't know what happens when we give $0$ a sign.  Limits were simply the closest I could think of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually for a sign one will want to have that the sign of $x$ is different from the sign of the opposite element to/the additive inverse of $x$.

Now, what does this mean for $0$. As $0$ is its own additive inverse one will either need to have a special sign for it or assign both signs to it.

Ultimately both lead to the same.

Indeed, in some languages, e.g., French, it is common that the positive reals include $0$, and so do the negative reals.

While in English it is common that neither includes them. 
Yet, note that in the Wikipedia page on [ordered fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field) the element $0$ is in fact an element of the positive cone (though not a positive element).

Comment: So I *must* assign both signs to $0$?  Or a special sign?  What is this special sign we could be assigning?

Comment: Yes, both or something special. It would make no sense to say $0$ is positive but not negative or vice versa. This would break things.  The special sign is often just $0$. Recall for example [the sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) it is $+1$ for $x>0$ it is $-1$ for $x<0$  and $0$ for $x=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Generally we don't refer to 0 as having any sign. Instead, it gets its own class. You could represent that as a symbol of you really wanted to, but the whole reason we use a negative sign is for simplicity... we could come up with a different numbering system for negative numbers so that no sign would be needed, but it's much easier to just mirror our positive reals to the negative reals with a sign in front. With 0, there is only one case, and it mirrors only itself, making a sign redundant. As a note, whether to include 0 as a natural number had been a long debate, and multiple notations exist to include or exclude it. You even get things like "whole numbers", "natural numbers", "non-negative integers" (the last doesn't include 0, since 0 isn't positive) and many more notations, both written out and symbolic.

**Edit:** I should note that some computer software uses $-0$. I can't remember off the top of my head, but some scripting for web pages differentiate between $0$ and $-0$, and the problem is very important when you are discussing Two's complement vs One's complement (I'll explain this onto you if you want, but there are great tutorials online!)
Tl;dr $-0 = 0$ for all intents and purposes.

Comment: I believe the phrase you're looking for is: "For all intents and purposes."

Comment: @goblin yep. Auto-correct on phone

Comment: :) $\;\;\,\,\!\!$

Comment: The (extremely common) IEEE 754 floating-point arithmetic standard has both a +0 and a -0. But IEEE floating point is different from mathematical arithmetic in many other ways also. For example addition is not associative.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the details, but this seems to have something to do with filters.

> **Definition 0.** Given a topological space $X$ and an element $x \in X$, define that $x^\star$ is the collection of all neighbourhoods of $x$. This happens to be a filter, called the *neighborhood filter of $X$.*
>
> **Definition 1.** Given a totally ordered set $X$ and an element $x \in X$, it should be possible to define $x^+$ and $x^-$ to be $x^*$ for two different ways of making $X$ into a topological space.

It should then be possible to define notions like "right-continuous" in terms of limits that make reference to $x^+$ and $x^-$. Perhaps we can even make the set $$\{x \mid x:\mathbb{R}\} \sqcup \{x^+ \mid x:\mathbb{R}\} \sqcup \{x^- \mid x:\mathbb{R}\} \sqcup \{x^\star \mid x:\mathbb{R}\}$$ into an algebraic structure in its own right. So for example, I imagine that we should have:

$$2 \cdot (3^+) = 6^+, \qquad (-2) \cdot 3^+ = (-6)^-$$

etc.

I've made this answer community wiki; can someone who understands the details spell them out here? This would help me, too.

Comment: um... too mathy?  Thank you though.

Comment: @SimpleArt, unfortunately, the question can't really be answered without getting "mathy"... But anyway, these aren't difficult concepts. You should be able to learn about topological spaces on YouTube, for example, if you don't know about them already.

Comment: @goblin I think what you want is more elementary. We simply take the induced topology on $A:=\{a \in X : a \geq x\}$. A function is right-continuous if its restriction to $A$ is continuous. Analogously for left-continuous.

However, I think this doesn't address OP's question (which, as Noah, I don't understand what it wants exactly either). You are focusing on the misleading examples he gave (right, left continuity), not on the "assigning a sign" aspect.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo, I could be wrong, but I think you're misreading the question. In my estimation, what the OP cares about are the entities $0^+$ and $0^-$, and is simply using the phrase "assigning a sign" due to a lack of familiar terminology to describe what's going on here.

Comment: @goblin Man, you can learn anything on the internet.

Comment: @SimpleArt, indeed :)

Comment: @goblin Maybe. But, for example, quid did not interpret it this way. And it seems many people didn't. This is just a reflex of the fact that the question, as is stated, is unclear (as Noah implicitly pointed out).